# Dynamic loose source routing in IP networks

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, boost, routes, ip

Okay guys, I have this idea to recreate a program wich could find the best rout in IP networks. I found one guy on the internet who did it, and he shared some code..but whatever I'm doing with it, I can't make it work. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 with latest BOOST libs, C++.

The IP protocol has a possibility of data transmission by the non-standard routes. therefore, at the IP-packege header, you can specify specific source routing option of IP-addresses list network routers through which the packege is forwarded for delivery to the addressee.
Simultaneous transmission of data over the standard and alternative routes will reduce the tense on the standard route and increase the bandwidth of the connection with the addressee.

The main goal of that project is increasing bandwidth of connections with user-defined route of simultaneous use of several channels of data, the plan was divided into sub-tasks:

1. Develop an algorithm to determine the connectivity of nodes IP-based network in a given direction.
2. Develop an algorithm of finding and selecting alternative routes of transmission data in a predetermined direction.
3. Create a software implementation of a method for dynamically determining the routes traffic based on the developed algorithms and source routing option of IP.
4. Conduct an experiment to evaluate the efficacy data using the developed software implementation.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/file_mapping.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::tr1;
using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::this_thread;
using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace boost::asio::ip;
using namespace boost::filesystem;
using namespace boost::system;
using namespace boost::interprocess;
using namespace boost::posix_time;

int send(char *host, unsigned short port, const char *file_path) {
    try {
        io_service _io_service;
        tcp::socket _socket(_io_service, tcp::v4());
        system::error_code _error_code;
        tcp::endpoint target_address(address_v4::from_string(host), port);
        _socket.connect(target_address);

        uintmax_t region_size = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
        uintmax_t _file_size = file_size(file_path);
        file_mapping _file_mapping(file_path, read_only);

        size_t written = 0;
        ptime start = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time();
        for (uintmax_t position = 0; position < _file_size; position += region_size) {
            mapped_region _mapped_region(_file_mapping, read_only, position, min(region_size, _file_size - position));
            written += write(_socket, buffer(_mapped_region.get_address(), _mapped_region.get_size()), transfer_all(),
                            _error_code);
        }
        ptime finish = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time();

        cout << "Sent " << written << " of " << _file_size << " in " << finish - start << endl;
        _socket.close();
        return 0;
    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
        return 1;
    }
}

int receive(unsigned short port, const char *file_name) {
    try {
        io_service _io_service;
        tcp::socket _socket(_io_service);

        path file_path(file_name);
        if (exists(file_path)) {
            remove(file_path);
        }

        const int buffer_size = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
        char _buffer[buffer_size];
        FILE *file = fopen(file_name, "wb");

        tcp::endpoint _endpoint(tcp::v4(), port);
        tcp::acceptor _acceptor(_io_service, _endpoint);
        system::error_code _error_code;

        _acceptor.accept(_socket);
        cout << "Request from " << _socket.remote_endpoint() << "\n";

        size_t received = 0;
        size_t portion = 0;
        ptime start = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time();
        do {
            portion = read(_socket, buffer(_buffer, buffer_size), _error_code);
            received += portion;
            fwrite(_buffer, 1, portion, file);
        } while (portion > 0);
        ptime finish = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time();

        cout << "Received " << received << " in " << finish - start << endl;
        _socket.close();
        fclose(file);
        return 0;
    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
        return 1;
    }
}

int check(char *file_name1, char *file_name2) {
    cout << "Checking ... ";
    cout.flush();
    FILE *file1 = fopen(file_name1, "rb");
    FILE *file2 = fopen(file_name2, "rb");
    const unsigned int buffer_size = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
    char buffer1[buffer_size];
    char buffer2[buffer_size];

    do {
        size_t red1 = fread(buffer1, 1, buffer_size, file1);
        size_t red2 = fread(buffer2, 1, buffer_size, file2);
        if (feof(file1) != feof(file2) || red1 != red2 || memcmp(buffer1, buffer2, red1)) {
            cout << "ERROR!!!" << endl;
            return -1;
        }
    } while (!feof(file1) && !feof(file2));

    cout << "OK" << endl;
    return 0;
}

int sendTest(char *destination, int port, int argc, char **argv) {
    io_service _io_service;
    tcp::endpoint target_address(address_v4::from_string(destination), port);
    tcp::socket _socket(_io_service, tcp::v4());
    system::error_code _error_code;

    if (argc > 0) {
        int route[argc + 1];
        ((char *)route)[0] = 1;
        ((char *)route)[1] = 131;
        ((char *)route)[2] = 3 + argc * 4;
        ((char *)route)[3] = 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
            route[i + 1] = inet_addr(argv[i]);
        }

        if (setsockopt(_socket.native_handle(), IPPROTO_IP, IP_OPTIONS, route, (argc + 1) * 4) < 0) {
            perror("can't set socket option");
        }
    }

    _socket.connect(target_address);
    std::cout << write(_socket, buffer("Test", 4), _error_code) << std::endl;

    _socket.close();
    return 0;
}

int main2(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc >= 2) {
        string option(argv[1]);
        if (argc >= 5 && option.compare("-s") == 0) {
            return send(argv[2], (unsigned short)atoi(argv[3]), argv[4]);
        } else if (argc >= 4 && option.compare("-r") == 0) {
            return receive((unsigned short)atoi(argv[2]), argv[3]);
        } else if (argc >= 4 && option.compare("-t") == 0) {
            return sendTest(argv[2], atoi(argv[3]), argc - 4, argv + 4);
        } else if (argc >= 4 && option.compare("-c") == 0) {
            return check(argv[2], argv[3]);
        }
    }
    cout << "Argument must be:" << endl << "\"-s HOST POST FILE_NAME\" for sender" << endl
        << "\"-r PORT FILE_NAME\" for receiver" << endl << "\"-c FILI_1_NAME FILE_2_NAME\" for receiver" << endl
        << "\"-t HOST PORT ROUTE_HOST_1 ...\" to test loose source send" << endl;
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::tr1::unordered_multimap<unsigned int, unsigned int> graph;
    graph.insert(std::make_pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>(1, 2));
    graph.insert(std::make_pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>(2, 1));
    graph.insert(std::make_pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>(1, 3));
    graph.insert(std::make_pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>(3, 1));
    graph.insert(std::make_pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>(3, 5));
    graph.insert(std::make_pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>(5, 3));
    graph.insert(std::make_pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>(2, 4));
    graph.insert(std::make_pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>(4, 2));
    graph.insert(std::make_pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>(1, 4));
    graph.insert(std::make_pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>(4, 1));
    graph.insert(std::make_pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>(1, 7));
    graph.insert(std::make_pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>(7, 1));
    graph.insert(std::make_pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>(5, 6));
    graph.insert(std::make_pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>(6, 5));
    graph.insert(std::make_pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>(5, 7));
    graph.insert(std::make_pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>(7, 5));
    graph.insert(std::make_pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>(8, 7));
    graph.insert(std::make_pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>(7, 8));
    graph.insert(std::make_pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>(4, 8));
    graph.insert(std::make_pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>(8, 4));
    graph.insert(std::make_pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>(8, 9));
    graph.insert(std::make_pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>(9, 8));
    graph.insert(std::make_pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>(9, 10));
    graph.insert(std::make_pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>(10, 9));
    list<list<unsigned int> *> routes;
    UIntUIntMap our_reverse;
    UIntUIntMap target_reverse;
    UIntSet intersections;
    boost::asio::lsr::router::findIntersections(graph, 1, 8, 4, intersections, our_reverse, target_reverse);
}
```

Sorry guys, I'm using ukrainian version of VS2012 and I can't show the warnings I have, you wouldn't understand them anyway

right now I have troubles with that code:

```
if (argc > 0) {
        int route[argc + 1];
        ((char*) route)[0] = 1;
        ((char*) route)[1] = 131;
        ((char*) route)[2] = 3 + argc * 4;
        ((char*) route)[3] = 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
            route[i + 1] = inet_addr(argv[i]);
        }
```

Comment: "I can't make it work" Can you be more specific? What did you do? What did you get? What did you expect to get?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I guess, in general the code is right, but I cant deal with those mistakes I get during compilation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't figure it all out, but the below is a fixed up version without some of atrocities

- all those `using namespace`s beg to conflict/interfere silently
- the tr1 dependency surely is obsolete even in VS by now

Now, the remaining things are to do with

- assuming unsigned characters (the literal 131 isn't directly supported on many compilers)
- using VLAs (which are a C things or a compiler extension, AFAIK)
- the **absense of** `boost::asio::lsr`

It seems you found the main program and the `lsr::findIntersections` code is missing.

Here's the cleaned up version, in case it helps you

```
//#include "stdafx.h"
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/file_mapping.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>
//#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
namespace sys = boost::system;
namespace bip = boost::interprocess;
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::posix_time::ptime;

int send(char *host, unsigned short port, const char *file_path) {
    try {
        asio::io_service io_service_;
        tcp::socket socket_(io_service_, tcp::v4());
        sys::error_code error_code_;
        tcp::endpoint target_address(asio::ip::address_v4::from_string(host), port);
        socket_.connect(target_address);

        uintmax_t region_size = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
        uintmax_t file_size_  = fs::file_size(file_path);

        bip::file_mapping file_mapping_(file_path, bip::read_only);

        size_t written = 0;
        ptime start = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time();
        for (uintmax_t position = 0; position < file_size_; position += region_size) {
            bip::mapped_region mapped_region_(
                    file_mapping_,
                    bip::read_only,
                    position,
                    std::min(region_size, file_size_ - position)
                );

            written += write(
                    socket_, 
                    asio::buffer(mapped_region_.get_address(), mapped_region_.get_size()),
                    asio::transfer_all(),
                    error_code_
                );
        }
        ptime finish = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time();

        std::cout << "Sent " << written << " of " << file_size_ << " in " << finish - start << std::endl;
        socket_.close();
    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int receive(unsigned short port, const char *file_name) {
    try {
        asio::io_service io_service_;
        tcp::socket socket_(io_service_);

        fs::path file_path(file_name);
        if (fs::exists(file_path)) {
            fs::remove(file_path);
        }

        const int buffer_size = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
        FILE *file            = fopen(file_name, "wb");
        char buffer_[buffer_size];

        tcp::endpoint   endpoint_(tcp::v4(),   port);
        tcp::acceptor   acceptor_(io_service_, endpoint_);
        sys::error_code error_code_;

        acceptor_.accept(socket_);
        std::cout << "Request from " << socket_.remote_endpoint() << "\n";

        size_t received = 0;
        size_t portion  = 0;
        ptime start     = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time();
        do {
            portion   = read(socket_, asio::buffer(buffer_, buffer_size), error_code_);
            received += portion;

            fwrite(buffer_, 1, portion, file);
        } while (portion > 0);

        ptime finish = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time();

        std::cout << "Received " << received << " in " << finish - start << std::endl;
        socket_.close();
        fclose(file);
    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int check(char *file_name1, char *file_name2) {
    std::cout << "Checking ... ";
    std::cout.flush();

    FILE *file1 = fopen(file_name1, "rb");
    FILE *file2 = fopen(file_name2, "rb");
    const unsigned int buffer_size = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
    char buffer1[buffer_size];
    char buffer2[buffer_size];

    do {
        size_t red1 = fread(buffer1, 1, buffer_size, file1);
        size_t red2 = fread(buffer2, 1, buffer_size, file2);
        if (feof(file1) != feof(file2) || red1 != red2 || memcmp(buffer1, buffer2, red1)) {
            std::cout << "ERROR!!!" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
    } while (!feof(file1) && !feof(file2));

    std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int sendTest(char *destination, int port, int argc, char **argv) {
    asio::io_service io_service_;
    tcp::endpoint target_address(asio::ip::address_v4::from_string(destination), port);
    tcp::socket socket_(io_service_, tcp::v4());
    sys::error_code error_code_;

    if (argc > 0) {
        int route[argc + 1];
        ((char *)route)[0] = 1;
        ((char *)route)[1] = 131;
        ((char *)route)[2] = 3 + argc * 4;
        ((char *)route)[3] = 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
            route[i + 1] = inet_addr(argv[i]);
        }

        if (setsockopt(socket_.native_handle(), IPPROTO_IP, IP_OPTIONS, route, (argc + 1) * 4) < 0) {
            perror("can't set socket option");
        }
    }

    socket_.connect(target_address);
    std::cout << write(socket_, asio::buffer("Test", 4), error_code_) << std::endl;

    socket_.close();
    return 0;
}

int main2(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc >= 2) {
        std::string option(argv[1]);
        if (argc >= 5 && option.compare("-s") == 0) {
            return send(argv[2], static_cast<unsigned short>(atoi(argv[3])), argv[4]);
        } else if (argc >= 4 && option.compare("-r") == 0) {
            return receive(static_cast<unsigned short>(atoi(argv[2])), argv[3]);
        } else if (argc >= 4 && option.compare("-t") == 0) {
            return sendTest(argv[2], atoi(argv[3]), argc - 4, argv + 4);
        } else if (argc >= 4 && option.compare("-c") == 0) {
            return check(argv[2], argv[3]);
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Argument must be:" << std::endl << "\"-s HOST POST FILE_NAME\" for sender" << std::endl
         << "\"-r PORT FILE_NAME\" for receiver" << std::endl << "\"-c FILI_1_NAME FILE_2_NAME\" for receiver" << std::endl
         << "\"-t HOST PORT ROUTE_HOST_1 ...\" to test loose source send" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::unordered_multimap<unsigned int, unsigned int> graph {
        {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {1, 3}, {3, 1}, {3, 5}, {5, 3}, {2, 4}, {4, 2}, {1, 4},
        {4, 1}, {1, 7}, {7, 1}, {5, 6}, {6, 5}, {5, 7}, {7, 5}, {8, 7}, {7, 8},
        {4, 8}, {8, 4}, {8, 9}, {9, 8}, {9, 10}, {10, 9} };

    std::list<std::list<unsigned int> *> routes;

    // here the guess work starts
    typedef std::set<unsigned int> UIntSet;
    typedef std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int> UIntUIntMap;

    UIntUIntMap our_reverse;
    UIntUIntMap target_reverse;
    UIntSet intersections;

    boost::asio::lsr::router::findIntersections(graph, 1, 8, 4, intersections, our_reverse, target_reverse);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @sehe so much for your answer and your help!! Btw I found those lsr files at other directory..so I have them, do I need to add them to the BOOST directory?

Comment: and I still get a lot of errors at this bit of code while compilating `if (argc > 0) {
        int route[argc + 1];
        ((char *)route)[0] = 1;
        ((char *)route)[1] = 131;
        ((char *)route)[2] = 3 + argc * 4;
        ((char *)route)[3] = 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
            route[i + 1] = inet_addr(argv[i]);
        }

        if (setsockopt(socket_.native_handle(), IPPROTO_IP, IP_OPTIONS, route, (argc + 1) * 4) < 0) {
            perror("can't set socket option");
        }
    }`

Comment: Why would you copy them? You obviously need to _use_ them. The code cannot compile unless some includes are added. Either share your project on github/bitbucket/etc. or sort it out yourself, I guess. (No guarantees that I can see what's wrong, but I _can_ have a look)

Comment: here it is https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5qJq9mJ0-JVS1pZTWM3Tzh3Tm8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: could you please check it out? @sehe

Comment: patience is golden (no need to @plink here; the post author always gets notified) - also 1337 o'clock get

Comment: Here's **[the stuff compiling](https://github.com/sehe/project1-to-Sehe/commits/master)** I use GCC though. Not really motivated to try MSVC today. The Makefile boils down to just `g++ -std=c++11 -g -O2 -I"/tmp/project1 to Sehe/" src/main.cpp` assuming you already have boost configured and compiled correctly. MSVC will [auto-link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#auto-linking) Boost System, Thread & Filesystem

Comment: DISCLAIMER: no clue whether it actually works. Still things wonky with that `131` assigned to `char`. Also, various [**evil** C-style casts](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/EXP05-CPP.+Do+not+use+C-style+casts) that might not be well-defined.

Comment: Thank you!!! My head is going to explode! haha so much code..I believe yours too. So what do I need to do now..use your `main.cpp` and continue digging at it? my boost is working fine so far

Comment: Try to compile it. Just add the `project1 to Sehe\\` directory to your includes. After that, good luck :)